# Jquery tab transitions

Tags: jquery, tabs, timeout, delay

I'm using some jquery tabs that basically just uses an ul of links to each corresponding id of the tab content.

What I'm trying to do is set a delay between each tab to display a loading indicator.  I've looked at several methods of doing this, but am not sure what would be the best method to use, i.e. using a .delay function, or setTimeout or something else entirely?

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Simple html example:

```
<div id="tabs">

<ul>
<li><a href="#1">Tab 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#2">Tab 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#3">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>

</div>

<div id="tab-content">


<div id="1">
Tab 1
</div>

<div id="2">
Tab 2
</div>

<div id="3">
Tab 3
</div>
```

Comment: delay- does it take some time to load your div contents or just you want to add random delay for each div to display?

Comment: Yeah, it may seem kind of counterintuitive I guess, but I need to add a "random" delay.

Comment: are you using any specific jquery library?

Comment: is you content of tab static? or loaded via ajax?

Comment: just using jquery...the content is static.